# Getting Error while creating Facebook Friend Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I using [tutorial](https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector/blob/master/index.html) to create facebook multi friend selector. Its not working and getting following error

```
fb.login() called when user is already connected
```

I understand that I should call `FB.logout` but from where when pop blockers are enabled by default?
Or I should use `FB.getLoginStatus` method to find whether the user in logged in or not. But if these method says not authorized then I can not call login() method. It will be blocked by pop up blockers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the login function as you needed, this library is just required to be called at the right place.

To keep the things simpler download the source from [here](https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector) instead, it works!